# GraphQL + Autofac

Tags: c#, graphql, autofac, graphql-dotnet

I'm exploring GraphQL at the moment. In one of my `ObjectGraphTypes` I want to inject a service implementation which queries EF about some addition data.

```
public class RoomType : ObjectGraphType<Room>
    {
        public RoomType(IUserRepository userRepository)
        {
            Field(x => x.Id).Description("Identifier for a room");
            Field(x => x.Name).Description("Name of the room");
            Field<ListGraphType<UserType>, IEnumerable<User>>().Name("Users").Resolve(ctx =>
            {
                var roomId = ctx.Source.Id;
                return userRepository.GetUsersInRoom(roomId);
            });
        }
    }
```

Where both RoomType and IUserRepository has been registed within in Autofac container. However, during execution the RoomType cannot be resolved as it's missing a parameterless constructor, which makes me think that its been construction via reflection and not via the container. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was in the Schema. You have to have an implementation of ISchema which is registered within the container. You also need to register an implementation of `IDependencyResolver` which is an interface in the GraphQl library (`GraphQL.IDependencyResolver`) like this:

```
 builder.Register<IDependencyResolver>(c =>
            {
                var context = c.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
                return new FuncDependencyResolver(type => context.Resolve(type));
            });
```

At the end, make sure that all of your `schemas`, `queries` and `types` are registered in autofac.